# How do I read a azure DevOps pipeline variable from my unit test code

Tags: azure, selenium

I have a pipeline running selenium tests on a single HostedAgent.  I would like to run the first test task on one browser and then run a second test task using a different browser.

So the idea is to use a variable for the first task to indicate browser one, read that into my code so my selenium driver can be switched to browser one (chrome), then once that completes, the second test task reads the second browser variable and makes my code switch the WebDriver to browser two (edge or firefox).

I don't want to do it via Categories passed to dotnet as filters, not very elegant.  Any ideas that do not consist of swimming across the English channel.